# Using MySQL instead of H2

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, h2

When I try to test a simple REST Service, to output the number of users in a web page, it gives a lot of errors. I'm using MySQL and while testing JPA Query in the console, I get the right answer. But when I try from the web page, it gives this errors:

> 01:07:43,647 WARN  [org.jboss.as.weld] (default task-1) WFLYWELD0052:
>   Using deployment classloader to load proxy classes for module
>   org.jboss.jts. Package-private access will not work. To fix this the
>   module should declare dependencies on [org.jboss.weld.core,
>   org.jboss.weld.spi] 01:07:43,731 INFO 
>   [org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator] (default
>   task-1) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory 01:07:43,801 WARN 
>   [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-1)
>   SQL Error: 42102, SQLState: 42S02 01:07:43,802 ERROR
>   [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-1)
>   Table "USERS" not found; SQL statement: select count(users0_.id) as
>   col_0_0_ from users users0_ [42102-193] 01:07:43,807 ERROR
>   [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling
>   request to /amd-project-1.0/api/users/count:
>   org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException:
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare
>   statement     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:78)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:222)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:193)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:455)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:229)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:135)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:355)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:138)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:215)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:227)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791)     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
>     at
>   io.opentracing.contrib.jaxrs2.server.SpanFinishingFilter.doFilter(SpanFinishingFilter.java:55)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:360)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
>     at
>   org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
>     at
>   org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
>     at
>   org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
>     at
>   org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare
>   statement     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1514)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1553)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.container.TypedQueryNonTxInvocationDetacher.getSingleResult(TypedQueryNonTxInvocationDetacher.java:69)
>     at
>   com.oraldveizi.amdproject.repository.UsersRepository.countAll(UsersRepository.java:36)
>     at
>   com.oraldveizi.amdproject.repository.UsersRepository$Proxy$_$$*WeldSubclass.countAll$$super(Unknown
>   Source)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.TerminalAroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceedInternal(TerminalAroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:51)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:78)
>     at
>   com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.transactional.TransactionalInterceptorBase.invokeInNoTx(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:195)
>     at
>   com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.transactional.TransactionalInterceptorSupports.doIntercept(TransactionalInterceptorSupports.java:53)
>     at
>   com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.transactional.TransactionalInterceptorBase.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:88)
>     at
>   com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.transactional.TransactionalInterceptorSupports.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorSupports.java:47)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.jboss.weld.interceptor.reader.SimpleInterceptorInvocation$SimpleMethodInvocation.invoke(SimpleInterceptorInvocation.java:73)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.executeAroundInvoke(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:84)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.executeInterception(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:72)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.invoke(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:56)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.invoke(CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.java:79)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.invoke(CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.java:68)
>     at
>   com.oraldveizi.amdproject.repository.UsersRepository$Proxy$*$$*WeldSubclass.countAll(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.oraldveizi.amdproject.endpoints.UsersEndpoint.countUsers(UsersEndpoint.java:41)
>     at
>   com.oraldveizi.amdproject.endpoints.UsersEndpoint$Proxy$*$$*WeldClientProxy.countUsers(Unknown
>   Source)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:139)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:509)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:399)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$0(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:363)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:355)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:365)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:337)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:310)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:439)
>     ... 56 more Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException:
>   could not prepare statement   at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:182)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:148)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1984)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1914)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1892)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:937)     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2689)     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2672)  at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2506)    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2501)    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:504)   at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:395)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:220)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1508)   at
>   org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1537)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1505)
>     ... 96 more Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "USERS"
>   not found; SQL statement: select count(users0*.id) as col_0_0_ from
>   users users0_ [42102-193]     at
>   org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
>     at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)     at
>   org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)  at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:5389)   at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1257)   at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleFromPart(Parser.java:1897)     at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:2045)     at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:1891)    at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1709)  at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1697)   at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:445)  at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:317)  at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:289)  at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:254)     at
>   org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:561)  at
>   org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:502)    at
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1203)
>     at
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:73)
>     at
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:676)
>     at
>   org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.doPrepareStatement(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:758)
>     at
>   org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.prepareStatement(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:744)
>     at
>   org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.prepareStatement(WrappedConnection.java:459)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:146)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172)

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

import static javax.transaction.Transactional.TxType.REQUIRED;
import static javax.transaction.Transactional.TxType.SUPPORTS;

@Transactional(SUPPORTS)
public class UsersRepository implements EntityInterface<Users, Long> {

@PersistenceContext(name = "projectPU")
private EntityManager entityManager;


public Users find(Long id) {
    return entityManager.find(Users.class, id);
}

public List<Users> findAll() {
    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT u FROM Users u ORDER BY u.username DESC");
    List<Users> usersList = query.getResultList();
    return usersList;
}


public Long countAll() {
    TypedQuery<Long> query = entityManager.createQuery(
            "SELECT COUNT(u) FROM Users u", Long.class);
    return query.getSingleResult();
}

@Transactional(REQUIRED)
public Users create(Users users) {
    entityManager.persist(users);
    return users;
}

public void delete(Long id) {
    entityManager.remove(entityManager.getReference(Users.class, id));

}



}
```

This is my UserRepository.java
and this is UserEndpoint.java

```
import javax.inject.Inject;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.util.List;

import static javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN;

@Path("/users")
public class UsersEndpoint {

@Inject
private UsersRepository usersRepository;

public Users find(Long id) {
    return usersRepository.find(id);
}

@GET
@Produces("text/html")
public Response getUsers() {
    List<Users> usersList =  usersRepository.findAll();

    if(usersList.size() == 0)
        return Response.status(Response.Status.NO_CONTENT).build();
    return Response.ok(usersList).build();
}

@GET
@Path("/count")
@Produces(TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response countUsers() {
    Long numberOfUsers = usersRepository.countAll();
    if(numberOfUsers == 0)
        return Response.status(Response.Status.NO_CONTENT).build();
    return Response.ok(numberOfUsers).build();
}
```

I don't have hibernate.cfg.xml, because i have inserted the data source from the Configuration Menu. How can I change to use MySQL instead of H2?

Comment: `Table "USERS" not found`. And ? Perhaps create the table

Comment: Table is already there. I said i can execute just fine jpa querys from the console. It gives those errors only when i try REST client

Comment: If "Table is already there" then it wont give that error. Post the PRECISE SQL that it is executing and then you can see if there are issues over case sensitivity of the table name etc ... because some RDBMS are sensitive. Maybe MySQL has an issue with the USERS keyword, and it needs quoting. Some JPA providers do that for you automatically and maybe yours doesnt. Maybe your JPA provider allows control over case of identifiers ...